# UV Mapping - During or After Building Process?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, import, workflow

I'm in the process of modeling a stave church, I've built it [3] times already. I had to because I'm learning from my mistakes while learning new things about blender each day.

My question is should I UV-unwrap each piece as I complete it, i.e the clock tower on side of building, the overhang roof etc? Or would it be OK to build the entire thing, then do the process of unwrapping?

I'm dying to get it done and UV-mapped so I can texture it either in Blender or import it over to UE4 and texture it there, or is it better to everything in Blender and then import?

Comment: Hello and welcome. The way this question is phrased is somewhat subjective and suggests opinion based answers. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541) should answer some of your questions. Unwrap as soon as you are done modelling. Texturing and materials in the destination application, in Blender only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, It's best for it to be fully finished before UV unwrapping, because you'll want all your parts to be on the same map.

(mainly because it's a bit less tedious to do it this way.)

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to UV-unwrap after the part is finished. if you model, unwrap and tweak the model later you'll most likely have to re UV-unwrap it again. 
i'll typically add materials as i go though just for super basic shading